# Hanging GPU when running simulations with JAX

Tags: gpu, simulation, jax

There are two instances where I encounter a programme (consisting of running a simulation) running on a single GPU to somewhat 'freeze' or 'hang', where the programme is still running in the GPU but without actually doing anything. The cause, or at least an ingredient, to this seems to be related to the function which generates trajectories, which looks something like this:

```
def run_trajectory(state, starting_time):
    state, trajectory = lax.scan(run_to_printout, state, xs=starting_time)
    return state, trajectory
```

where the `run_to_printout` function runs a forward simulation to a point where we 'print out' or sample the trajectory state. This function itself is a function of the apply function of a simulator integrator from the JAX MD simulate package. In my programme this function gets JIT'ed.

The two instances where I encounter GPU 'hanging' is as follows:

1. When a long simulation is run i.e. a simulation which lasts several hours. In this case the simulation will finish, but the programme will freeze at the code right after the simulation. There was even one instance where there was an error right after the simulation and the error message appeared, but the programme still 'hung' and didn't terminate thereafter.
2. When iteratively generating trajectories with different `run_trajectory` functions (i.e. parameterised with different energy functions) in a `for` loop say, there seems to be a threshold to the number of times (I may use the particular `run_trajectory` function several times per iteration) this function is used over the `for` loop, such that once completed, the programme seems the hang at the code right after. Both the CPU and GPU memories seem to have not overflowed at these instances.

Unfortunately, this is all the information I think I can provide regarding this issue - hopefully it may cry out a particular issue to some reader. Please let me know if you would like more information about the setup or if you have any probing suggestions. Many thanks!